# multiple select box use jquery to confirm atleast one option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box that I need to check with jquery on mouseleave if there's an option selected however suggestions like `$('#category').attr("selectedIndex")` returns undefined even when an option has been selected.

HTML below:

```
<select id="category" multiple="multiple" class="category">
    {% for category in categories %}
       <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I have Django dump a list of options so for the above options list. I'd prefer if the code can filter by select id `category` so for it doesn't intefer with any other select boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#category").on('focusout',function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$("#category option:selected").index()
```

or

```
$("#category").prop("selectedIndex")
```

I think .prop is for the newer versions of jquery.